# How to use "react-native-copilot" to navigate from one screen to another, when user clicks on "Finish" button of tooltip

Tags: react-native, navigation

I am trying to navigate to new screen when user clicks on "Finish" button of "react-native-copilot", but I am not getting any way to do so. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show me the code that's in trouble.

Comment: I have found the way to do so using "  this.props.copilotEvents.on('stop', () => {
      // Copilot tutorial finished!
    });". But I have come up with another issue. Now I am trying to implement "Custom tooltip component" functionality of "react-native-copilot". But onPress is not working after implementing it i.e.  onPress of  "skip", "next", "finish"etc. is not working and hence only first CopilotStep is showing.

Answer (score 0):

use stepchange method to track the order number, you know which one is the last number, so track it and put a condition.

```
if(orderNumber = X) {
    navigation.navigate(...)
     }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).